# Redirection admin and user in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, dashboard, rails-admin

I am facing an issue in redirection of admin and user to two different pages. I created an admin column and set it as boolean,

Used a `gem 'rails_admin'` to create admin dashboard. And it is working, like when admin_user is login in then only we have admin dashboard.

Now can anyone say how can I redirect both admin to admin home and user to user home page.

Comment: Are you using devise for authentication?

Comment: Yes,devise is used for authentication, and admin is set by using console    u = User.first,  u.admin = true. So one of my user is admin. @Hackman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using devise you can add to `application_controller` sth like this:

```rb
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  current_user.admin? ? admin_path : user_path
end
```

More info: https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise%2FControllers%2FHelpers:after_sign_in_path_for

Comment: Yes.and admin is set by using console u = User.first, u.admin = true.  @stolarz